# Firebase data still present after delete

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm using firebase, and in each user object, I also keep his favorites. The structure looks like this:
[image]

As you can see in the favorites object I have only one record, **I had 2** but I manually deleted one from the firebase console.

**The problem is that in my application it still shows me 2 records.**

[image]

I'm using Ionic and Angular Fire package.

```
this.userService.getUser(this.loggedUser.uid).take(1).subscribe(user => {
  console.log('count', user[0].favorites.length); //2
  for (let i = 0; i < user[0].favorites.length; i++) {
    this.userService.getUserByKey(user[0].favorites[i]).subscribe(favorite => {
      this.businesses.push(favorite);
    })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not subscribed anynore because of take(1), remove it and you'll be subscribed so then if you remove a record from firebase console, it'll disapear from the UI

```
 this.userService.getUser(this.loggedUser.uid).subscribe(user => ... )
```